# Running GUI on a headless linux with a display connected

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, operating-system, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm working on a RPI zero W with a connected 7inch display. I want to develop a GUI application for it with Tkinter for Python. I want to use this for a PC stats monitor that I would develop myself so I want a small footprint and I thought using like a better PI would be an overkill and would defeat the purpose (but I'm open for changing this if need be).

I'm running a headless Raspberry OS and I can see the terminal displayed on the display itself, now I just want to overlay the GUI app over the terminal. I'm running headless for faster boot and lower resource cost on the CPU.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
import sys
import os

if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')

root = Tk()


#Creating a Label Widget
myLabel = Label(root, text="Hello World!")
#Shoving it onto screen
myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When starting the app I get a return:

```
no display found. Using :0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gui_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You've got me confused. You are running *"headless"*, which means no screen, but you have a screen? You don't have an X11 server and are surprised an X11 client can't run?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining properly. I'm running raspbian lite. That version is not headless per se it just doesn't have GUI.

Comment: You need to run the X server (desktop environment) in order to run other GUI applications.

Comment: Thank you I've also found this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=133691

I'm still trying to find how to run the application without a window manager and other stuff like that

Comment: How complicated a GUI do you need? Dialog boxes, file choosers, multiple windows, scrollboxes or just simple line graphics? You might be able to just use ImageMagick and the framebuffer. Or SFML. Or Qt on framebuffer.

Comment: Or maybe `ncurses` or ANSI graphics?

Comment: I don't plan to use complex graphics and GUI elements, some animated bar graphs or charts with some fancy colors overlayed over a background probably. That will be over the entire screen. No windows and scrollboxes.

Comment: Ok so I'm able to start an xserver but it seems my python fails with the same issue. It can't find a display.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58816979/2836621 You could maybe generate your graphics with `matplotlib` and blit them to the screen as I show in that answer. That does not require an X server.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was able to get the thing running with Tkinter after some tweaking. It seems my non standard display resolution also played a role so I had to adjust the CVT settings in boot file. I'll simply boot to the GUI and straight to the app. If there's any performace issues I'll upgrade the PI.

Comment: there is [xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) which creates fake X server and you can some run GUI programs without real X server and without displaying window. And there is python module which can use it [xvfbwrapper](https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper)

Comment: Does the link help? https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/getting-started-with-raspberry-pi-zero-w-headless-setup-without-monitor

Answer (score 0):

To run a graphics software in a headless environment, you need a graphics library to render your software and also support all inputs including mouse, touch, etc. And you have to connect your software to that library, which is a difficult task.

Therefore, the Pyimgui framework does this for you.

The imGUI framework is in C++, and "Pyimgui" is a rewritten version of this framework in Python.

You can easily create your own software and along with graphic libraries such as openGL,
vulkan, and SDL output and run on your headless Linux.
This is the repository link of this framework:
https://github.com/pyimgui/pyimgui